# How to remove the border and black spaces from a custom dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme

I want to create and show a custom dialog:

```
AlertDialog dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.BubbleDialog).create();
dialog.setView(detailsView,0,0,0,0);
dialog.show();
```

And that's the style:

```
<style name="BubbleDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

However, I'm getting:

[image]

If you look closely, you can see there's a dark grey border around the view, and also, because the corners are rounded, there are small black spaces where a rectangular corner would be.

How can I get rid of all that? I tried playing with themes and such, but so far to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: Make the Dialog background color completely transparent.

Comment: Well, if you look at the style XML I attached above, you will see I defined the background color as transparent. The view itself I want to be white.

Comment: `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));` try that